# ¿Cómo puedo generar un numpy array desde un CSV y acceder a los datos con datatype?

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, numpy

Estoy trabajando con datos de precios de divisas y necesito generar un `np.array` pero no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, mis datos son los siguientes y tienen esta estructura (archivo csv):

```
 fecha hora, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre
2016.11.04 16:56,1.11386,1.11394,1.11383,1.11386
2016.11.04 16:57,1.11387,1.11389,1.11383,1.11386
2016.11.04 16:58,1.11387,1.11412,1.11385,1.11407
2016.11.04 16:59,1.11407,1.11408,1.11361,1.11378
```

Necesito tenerlos de este modo (ejemplo):

```
([(1459388100, 29.799999237060547, 29.799999237060547, 29.799999237060547, 29.799999237060547, 148929.0, 450030016.0),
   (1459388400, 29.799999237060547, 29.979999542236328, 29.709999084472656, 29.920000076293945, 10395.0, 31069984.0)], dtype=[('tiempo', '<i4'), ('apertura', '<f4'), ('alto', '<f4'), ('bajo', '<f4'), ('cierre', '<f4')])
```

Trate de hacerlo de estas dos formas pero no me resulta:

```python
import numpy as np 

datos = np.genfromtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',')
```

```python
import numpy as np

datos = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Todo para poder acceder al array para crear un gráfico de la siguiente manera:

```python
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
candlestick2_ohlc(ax,precios['apertura'],precios['alto'],precios['bajo'],precios['cierre'])
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: No me da error, de hecho crea un array, pero no se como generar el datetype para acceder a cada objeto del array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir el array que quieres con los datos en el formato que das en el ejemplo hay varios puntos a resolver:

- Para especificar el tipo de dato debes usar el parámetro `dtype` y pasarle los tipos. Los tipos se pueden pasar de varias formas como puedes ver en la [documentación](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) , yo se los paso en una cadena.
- Hay un problema, quieres la fecha en `int` (por la cifra supongo que serán segundos desde época) y además el formato no es estandar al ser `2016.11.04 16:56` y no `2016-11-04 16:56`. Para solucionarlo podemos usar la biblioteca estandar [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) para transformar ese string en segundos desde época. En el ejemplo que te doy lo realiza la función `convertir` que se le pasa a [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) indicandole que lo aplique sobre los datos de la columna 0:

  - [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) parsea la cadena usando el patrón que le damos y la trasforma en tipo `datetime` válido.
  - [`timestap()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) obtenemos los segundos desde época.
- Por último, si usas [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) con un csv que tiene en la primera fila los nombres de las columnas necesitas indicarle explicitamente este hecho mediante:

  ```
  names = True
  ```

El código aplicado sobre tus datos ejemplo es:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import numpy as np



convertir = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M').timestamp()
datos = np.genfromtxt('datos_tratados.csv', dtype='i4,f4,f4,f4,f4', delimiter=',', converters={0:convertir}, names = True)
print(datos)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick2_ohlc(ax,datos['apertura'],datos['alto'],datos['bajo'],datos['cierre'])
plt.show()
```

Esto nos imprime el array:

```
[ (1478274960, 1.113860011100769, 1.1139400005340576, 1.1138299703598022, 1.113860011100769)
 (1478275020, 1.1138700246810913, 1.1138900518417358, 1.1138299703598022, 1.113860011100769)
 (1478275080, 1.1138700246810913, 1.1141200065612793, 1.1138499975204468, 1.1140700578689575)
 (1478275140, 1.1140700578689575, 1.1140799522399902, 1.113610029220581, 1.1137800216674805)]
```

Y nos grafica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! por dios que solución tan elegante, incluso me resolvió otras dudas con la generación de arrays y el parametro converters, gracias.

Comment: Una sola pregunta más, si no es mucha moelstia, ¿Cómo puedo formatear el eje x con las fechas exactas, lo intento así pero no me sale: `xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%m.%d %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)`